# Where are Azure WebJob QueueTrigger-ed Invocation Logs Stored?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I'm trying to find the queue messages processed in a QueueTrigger webjob. The problem is I didn't save these messages anywhere after processing and now I need them. I know they're available in the SCM WebJobs Dashboard at

> https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions/invocations/{invocation-id}

...if I know the {invocation-id}. I have a couple hundred processed messages that I'm trying to retrieve for a specific date range so going page-by-page in a web browser isn't practical.

Does anyone know where these logs are stored that SCM is displaying? I've looked in the `azure-jobs-host-output` and `azure-webjobs-dashboard` and can't find the messages anywhere. I've also looked in `\data\jobs\continuous\{webjob}\job_log.txt`, but this appears to only be the Console.output of a job and not the triggering CloudQueueMessage data which was passed to the webjob function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my research, the detailed invocation logs are under `azure-webjobs-dashboard\functions\instances` as follows:

[image]

Moreover, the list records for Invocation Log are under `azure-webjobs-dashboard\functions\recent\flat` as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the link between `azure-webjobs-dashboard\functions\recent\flat` and `azure-webjobs-dashboard\functions\instances`. The `flat` blob has the "reverse" timestamp prefix (`DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`) which allows me to find the corresponding instance in the `instances` blob, which is missing this prefix and the Last Mod date of the `instance` blob is completely misleading.